# Subscribing to inner Observable inside merge map, is it bad practice?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need to make a call to an api and when the data arrives I have 2 things to do:

1. Update a set of data
2. Make another call to an api with the result of an observable to update a second set of data.

I am using a mergeMap that makes the call and subscribes, and mergeMap just returns the data passed in as an observable. I am new to Rx, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Is there a way to avoid managing subscriptions manually overall? for the end data I could just use async pipe on the ui.

Here is the link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hwjrsh)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to subscribe inside the `mergeMap` operator.

The idea of the [mergeMap/flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) is to flat the Observable chain.
For example, if you did like this:

```
const source = Rx.of('Hello');
source.map(val => doOperationThatReturnsObservable(val)).map(f)
```

The function `f` would receive an `Observable`.

If you did like this:

```
const source = Rx.of('Hello');
source.mergeMap(val => doOperationThatReturnsObservable(val)).map(f)
```

The function `f` would receive the value of the second Observable.
In other words, mergeMap, concatMap, swichtMap are functions that allow you to combine observables or map value to observables while maintaining the stream of data.

Specific for the problem you described, I think you could solve like this:

```js
const firstApiCall = createFirstApiCallObservable();
const secondApiCall = firstApiCall.mergeMap(data => createSecondApiCallObservableFromData(data));

// If you need to do the updates in the same time:
Observable.zip(firstApiCall, secondApiCall, 
  (data1, data2) => [data1, data2])
  .subscribe(data => {
    data1 = data[0];
    data2 = data[1];
    doFirstUpdate(data1);
    doSecondUpdate(data2);
  });
  
// If you can do the updates separatly:
firstApiCall.subscribe(data1 => doFirstUpdate(data1));
secondApiCall.subscribe(data2 => doSecondUpdate(data2));
```

Comment: so, thats why inside flatMap I should do: flatMap(v => return apicall.get())?

Comment: Yeah, if `apicall.get()` returns an Observable, this "chain" of observable will be flattened into one Observable.